# Change select options when I click on a anchor tag

Tags: html, jquery, css, html-select

What I'm trying to do is **replace/change** the text inside the `select` tag when I click on the anchor tag. As you will see it only changes it once. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="slideOne" href="#blue">Blue Product</a></li>
        <li><a id="slideTwo" href="#red">Red Product</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<select>
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Color</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>​
```

**JS**

```
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
    $('select').val(this.id).change();
});​
```

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLrbk/1/).

Comment: There is no relation between your ids ("slideOne") and your values ("blue").

Answer (score 3):

Use a class name to stash your colour attributes, then use these in your event.

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="slideOne" class="blue" href="#blue">Blue Product</a></li>
        <li><a id="slideTwo" class="red" href="#red">Red Product</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
    $('select').val($(this).attr('class'))
});
```

​

Comment: what if the value for the `select` `option` is different than the class? @diodeus for ex. - http://jsfiddle.net/RLrbk/2/

Comment: There are a number of ways of dealing with this, including using "data-" elements, which can also be easily accessed via jQuery.

Comment: would that make it compatible with ie7? since it is a html5 attribute?

Comment: jQuery takes care of it on ie 7. no prob.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the id of the anchors which don't match your options at all.

You can do it like this

```
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
    $('select').val(this.href.split('#')[1]).change();
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/DaVFw/)

as @destroy suggested you can use .slice(1) also

```
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
    $('select').val($(this).attr('href').slice(1)).change();
});​
```

[Slice Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/pKQVc/)

or .replace()

```
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
    $('select').val($(this).attr('href').replace('#','')).change();
});​
```

[Replace Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/CT5ec/)

Comment: Instead of `split('#')[1]`, you might use `slice(1)`.

Comment: True.. I was wondering why slice() wasn't working before.. found out now lol http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/DaVFw/1/

Comment: Oh yes... href might not be so easy to use... Use `$(this).attr('href')`.

Comment: what if the `select` `option` is different than the `id`?

Answer (score 0):

The id values of anchor's are not mapping with the Values in the select .. So there is no relationship between them..

Try using the **href** attribute instead...

Answer (score 0):

Your js should look like:

```
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
    var lookup={
        'slideOne' : 'blue',
        'slideTwo' : 'red'
    }
    var target = lookup[this.id];
    $("select option[val=" + target +"]").attr("selected","selected") ;
});​
```

A better option would be to use the href attribute which could elminate reliance on the lookup object